# A odoo server and a IIS server are running on the same machine.How can I point a domain with IIS to odoo without showing the port?

Tags: postgresql, iis, odoo, odoo-8

IIS is managing multiple website on the port 80, odoo is running on the port 8069.
How can I manage to point a domain in IIS to the odoo server without showing the port in the url?

Right now I have odoo running on http://mywebsite.org:8069
I would like it to be http://mywebsite.org

I cannot make the odoo server running on the port 80, because IIS is managing multiple sites there

Comment: This is not a programming question, voting to close as off-topic. But still, here's where you should start to read. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Below link helped me, try this:
http://www.tecmint.com/install-openerp-odoo-with-nginx-on-centos-and-debian/.